# Android HTML to docx Docx4j issues

Tags: java, android, docx4j

I am trying to convert html string to docx using the below code as per 
[github code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/XhtmlToDocxAndBack.java) recommended on previous stackoverflow questions.

I added the following libraries other than the ones used for Android docx to HTML by docx4j:
1. docx4j-importXHTML-3.2.2.jar
2. itext-2.1.7.jar
3. xml-renderer-3.0.0.jar
4. xalan-2.7.0.jar

The following is the android version of code in XhtmlToDocxAndBack.java :

```
       try {
                String html = "<html><head><title>Import me</title></head><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>";

                WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

                XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
                XHTMLImporter.setDivHandler(new DivToSdt());

                wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(html, null));

                System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(wordMLPackage
                        .getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

                wordMLPackage.save(new File("/sdcard/OUT_from_XHTML.docx"));


            } catch (Docx4JException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Error I receive:

```
Error:(166, 34) error: cannot access XHTMLImporter
class file for org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporter not found
```

Error I receive if I comment out XHTMLImporter.setDivHandler(new DivToSdt()):

```
Error:(168, 34) error: cannot access XHTMLImporter
class file for org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporter not found
```

Error I receive if I comment out wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(html, null)); as well:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/ListHelper.class
```

I should mention docx to html is working fine in Android studio but the above error is buggy. Please tell me how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somebody please answer this question. I am stuck at this issue.

Comment: did you found a solution?